# Find the nearest/closest value in a sorted List

Tags: java, binary-search

I was wondering if it is possible to find the closest element in a sorted `List` for a element **that is not** in the list.

For example if we had the values [1,3,6,7] and we are looking for the element closest to 4, it should return 3, because 3 is the biggest number in the array, that is smaller than 4.

I hope it makes sense, because English is not my native language.

Comment: and the arraylist is sorted in this case...

Comment: Do you want the closest number (which might be larger) or the closest number less than the query value?

Comment: So, what would be the outcome for having 3 and 5 (in your case). You choose the lower one because there were no upper closer...but what if you have those two?

Comment: Iterate through the list until you find the first value, which is bigger than your `x` or the the end of the list is reached. Then check the last two values.

Comment: @blazetopher less than, like in this case 3 was less than 4...

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ In that case the outpuut would still be 3, because 3 is smaller than 4..

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt yeah that was my initial thought, but for large arraylists it takes waaaaaaaay too long..

Comment: @KorhanOzturk Hii, no, it is not the same question, because the way with the loop is the obvious one. I am concerned here also for the speed....

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because the collection is sorted, you can do a modified binary search in `O( log n )` :

```
    public static int search(int value, int[] a) {

        if(value < a[0]) {
            return a[0];
        }
        if(value > a[a.length-1]) {
            return a[a.length-1];
        }

        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;

        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = (hi + lo) / 2;

            if (value < a[mid]) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else if (value > a[mid]) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else {
                return a[mid];
            }
        }
        // lo == hi + 1
        return (a[lo] - value) < (value - a[hi]) ? a[lo] : a[hi];
    }
```

Since most of the code above is binary search, you can leverage the  [`binarySearch(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte%5B%5D,byte)) provided in the std library and examine the value of the `insertion point`:

```java
    public static int usingBinarySearch(int value, int[] a) {
        if (value <= a[0]) { return a[0]; }
        if (value >= a[a.length - 1]) { return a[a.length - 1]; }

        int result = Arrays.binarySearch(a, value);
        if (result >= 0) { return a[result]; }

        int insertionPoint = -result - 1;
        return (a[insertionPoint] - value) < (value - a[insertionPoint - 1]) ?
                a[insertionPoint] : a[insertionPoint - 1];
    }
```

Comment: Eventhough is has a little "bug" when the element that is supposed to be the result, happens to be the one before the last one, the result comes as the last one insted... any idea why that is? For example in the array if the number is 10 and the array is {1,3,5,7,9,11} the result comes as 11 which is wrong, but if the array is {1,3,5,7,9,11,12} the result comes as 9, which is the correct one! Any idea ?

Comment: Well, in `{1,3,5,7,9,11}` both 9 and 11 are equally close to 10, so you can't really have **the** closest element

Comment: As a matter of fact. since an empty array is a valid input, you could have 0 1, or 2 closest elements

Comment: Wrong implementation !! search(7, new int[]{4, 8, 12}) returns 4. Should return 8.

Comment: the bug in this code is the last return statement. At the end of the loop, lo points to the ceil and hi points to the floor of the key (due to the while condition check). Hence the correct return statement will be:`return (a[lo] - value) < (value - a[hi]) ? a[lo] : a[hi]`;

Comment: Almost - also need to account for the case where hi < 0 or lo > a.length

Comment: You want to check `abs(a[lo]-value) < abs(a[hi]-value)` to find the closest in absolute value and handle negative numbers.

Comment: @Joel No need because it will always be non-negative

Comment: @Michael why will it always be non-negative?

Answer (score 21):

You need `Array.binarySearch`, [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)).

> Returns: index of the search key, if it is contained in the array;
>   otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as
>   the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index
>   of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements
>   in the array are less than the specified key.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the suggestion, but I thought if there was a way without using anything like that. For example I tried modifying the binarysearch method..but I had no luck so far

Comment: Also, note that `Array.binarySearch` isn't stable when there are duplicates in the target array.

Answer (score 5):

Considering using `NavigableSet`, in particular `higher` and `lower`.

Comment: Is there an example?

Answer (score 4):

Andrey's answer is correct. Just expanding on it a bit.

No need to reinvent the wheel when you can use the built in binary search.

You can find the indices with:

```
int leftIndex = (-Collections.binarySearch(allItems, key) - 2);
int rightIndex = (-Collections.binarySearch(allItems, key) - 1);
```

The item in the list will need to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).
Simple types like `String` and `Integer` already implement this. Here's an example https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework.

Depending on your use case you may want to do `index = Math.max(0, index)` after the binary search just to be safe.

---

Update:
As pointed out by sundar, if there are duplicates in the array then binary search will not return accurate results. So perhaps if binary search fails then you can default to a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to achieve the result-

1. lower_bound
2. binary search

I prefer to use the lower_bound method, it's short :)

```cpp
int pos=lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),value);
if(pos!=0&&target!=v[pos])
    if(abs(v[pos]-value)>abs(value-v[pos-1]))
        pos=pos-1;
```

For binary search, you can refer to the above answers, as my code will seem like a copy paste of their code. Note that I have declared the array globally here.

```cpp
binarysearch(int low,int high,int val)
{
    if(val<=arr[0])
        return 0;
    if(val>=arr[n-1])
        return arr[n-1];
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(v[mid]>val)
            return binarysearch(low,mid-1,val);
        else if(v[mid]<val)
            return binarysearch(mid+1,high,val);
        else return mid;
    }
    if(abs(val-v[low])>=abs(val-v[high]))
        return high;
    else 
        return low;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking off the top of my head, if you need to find all closest values in a sorted list, you can find *a* closest value, then find all values with the same distance away from the target. Here, I use binary search 3 times:

- First to find *a* closest value
- Second to find the left-most closest value
- Third to find the right-most closest value

In Python:

```
def closest_value(arr, target):
  def helper(arr, target, lo, hi, closest_so_far):
    # Edge case
    if lo == hi:
      mid = lo
      if abs(arr[mid] - target) < abs(arr[closest_so_far] - target):
        closest_so_far = mid
      return closest_so_far

    # General case
    mid = ((hi - lo) >> 1) + lo

    if arr[mid] == target:
      return mid

    if abs(arr[mid] - target) < abs(arr[closest_so_far] - target):
      closest_so_far = mid

    if arr[mid] < target:
      # Search right
      return helper(arr, target, min(mid + 1, hi), hi, closest_so_far)
    else:
      # Search left
      return helper(arr, target, lo, max(mid - 1, lo), closest_so_far)


  if len(arr) == 0:
    return -1
  return helper(arr, target, 0, len(arr) - 1, arr[0])


arr = [0, 10, 14, 27, 28, 30, 47]

attempt = closest_value(arr, 26)
print(attempt, arr[attempt])
assert attempt == 3

attempt = closest_value(arr, 29)
print(attempt, arr[attempt])
assert attempt in (4, 5)


def closest_values(arr, target):
  def left_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, lo, hi):
    # Base case
    if lo == hi:
      diff = arr[lo] - target
      if abs(diff) == abs_diff:
        return lo
      else:
        return lo + 1

    # General case
    mid = ((hi - lo) >> 1) + lo
    diff = arr[mid] - target
    if diff < 0 and abs(diff) > abs_diff:
      # Search right
      return left_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, min(mid + 1, hi), hi)
    elif abs(diff) == abs_diff:
      # Search left
      return left_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, lo, max(mid - 1, lo))
    else:
      # Search left
      return left_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, lo, max(mid - 1, lo))


  def right_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, lo, hi):
    # Base case
    if lo == hi:
      diff = arr[lo] - target
      if abs(diff) == abs_diff:
        return lo
      else:
        return lo - 1

    # General case
    mid = ((hi - lo) >> 1) + lo
    diff = arr[mid] - target
    if diff < 0 and abs(diff) > abs_diff:
      # Search right
      return right_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, min(mid + 1, hi), hi)
    elif abs(diff) == abs_diff:
      # Search right
      return right_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, min(mid + 1, hi), hi)
    else:
      # Search left
      return right_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, lo, max(mid - 1, lo))


  a_closest_value = closest_value(arr, target)
  if a_closest_value == -1:
    return -1, -1

  n = len(arr)
  abs_diff = abs(arr[a_closest_value] - target)
  left = left_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, 0, a_closest_value)
  right = right_helper(arr, target, abs_diff, a_closest_value, n - 1)
  return left, right


arr = [0, 10, 14, 27, 27, 29, 30]

attempt = closest_values(arr, 28)
print(attempt, arr[attempt[0] : attempt[1] + 1])
assert attempt == (3, 5)

attempt = closest_values(arr, 27)
print(attempt, arr[attempt[0] : attempt[1] + 1])
assert attempt == (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another O(log n) easy to understand solution using binary search:

```
public class Solution {
    static int findClosest(int arr[], int n, int target)
    {
        int l=0, h=n-1, diff=Integer.MAX_VALUE, val=arr[0];
        while(l<=h)
        {
            int mid=l+(h-l)/2;
            if(Math.abs(target-arr[mid])<diff)
            {
                diff= Math.abs(target-arr[mid]);
                val=arr[mid];
            }
            if(arr[mid]<target)
                l=mid+1;
            else
                h=mid-1;
        }
        return val;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findClosest(new int[]{1,3,6,7}, 4, 3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the easiest way is simply to iterate over the sorted list, checking each item.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(3);
ints.add(6);
ints.add(7);

Collections.sort(ints);

int target = 4;
int nearest = 0;

for (int i : ints)
{
    if (i <= target) {
        nearest = i;
    }
}

System.out.println(nearest);
```

This outputs the largest item in the list which is less than or equal to the `target`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I forgot to mention, that I wanted to do it (I have to) with using only the arraylist, it's methods, and of course other help methods (That I write for example)

Comment: Its a sorted list. This is not efficient

Comment: This is a linear time complexity. In a sorted list, you can use binary search to have logarithmic complexity.