# How do I search a Realm database to get the closest date, if no match was found?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a realm database in swift, that has time-series data

So I have **two** objects

```
Object1: LastLogin(Epoch), name(String)
Object2: Logintime(Epoch), points(Int)
```

What I would like to do is take the `LastLoginTime` and use that to search the Object2s `LoginTime`, if no match, then find the closest.

My goal, is to make `object1` have the points value.

Thank you

EDIT:

I was thinking that if there is no other way, then I could convert the epoch to dates in swift, however then I would be in the same situation where I would need to search for the closest date on the realm database, there does not seem to be a clear way to do this.

Comment: There's no built in method of Realm that would do this for you, so you'll need to implement your own search algorithm.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I kind of guessed that, but was not sure. I posted an answer in case anyone else comes across this problem. Thanks Dávid

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I have just thought of. If you have a faster way or a better way then please say.

Frist thing I would do is get the list of Object2 and then sort them via timestamp.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let object2List = realm.objects(Object2.self).sorted(byKeyPath: Logintime)
```

We now have a list of object2, not in memory, that is sorted by loginTime.

After that, I searched up a closest integer algorithm and found one in java on SO. This is the conversion:

```
func search(_ value: Int, _ a: [Int]) -> Int {

if(value < a[0]) {
    return a[0];
}
if(value > a[a.count-1]) {
    return a[a.count-1];
}

var lo = 0;
var hi = a.count - 1;

while (lo <= hi) {
    var mid = (hi + lo) / 2;

    if (value < a[mid]) {
        hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (value > a[mid]) {
        lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
        return a[mid];
    }
}
// lo == hi + 1
return (a[lo] - value) < (value - a[hi]) ? a[lo] : a[hi];
}
var testInt = 200;

var list = [150,190, 350, 908]

search(testInt,list) //=> 190
```

I got this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245398/9201306

If the link no longer works for some reason, he just says "If the array is sorted you can do a modified binary search in log n operations:"

Hope that helps