# How to find the closest element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I've tried looking for the answer to this question, but I haven't had a lot of luck. Basically I am asked to create the Fibonacci Code, and then allow a user input to look for there input in the sequence. If its in the sequence then it shows what index. If its not then it shows the two closest numbers to it.

So if a user inputs 4, the nearest elements would be 3 and 5 and the indexes would be 4 and 5.

I'm basically struggling with finding the nearest elements. I'm not exactly sure how to do it. 
****update****
So I did figure it out thank you

Comment: I suggest that you take a step back from the code and describe the steps to solve this problem **in words**. For example, you can start with 1. Ask the user to enter a number. 2. Generate the first fibonacci number. Then what is step 3? Step 4? Keep going...

Comment: I guess creating an array of fibonacci no and then doing binary search on it will do good..when exact match is not found you can return adjacent elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the nearest/closest value in a sorted List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245166/find-the-nearest-closest-value-in-a-sorted-list)

Answer (score 2):

1.Store the previous Fibonacci number in a buffer (you can initialize with -1)

2.update the buffer after every new number is calculated.

3.if the current number is not equal to the new number

3.A check if the number is greater than buffer and less than the new number

3.A.1)If yes, those two are your nearest numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Fibonacci {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userInput;
    Fibonacci.fibonacciAlgor(5);

}

public static void fibonacciAlgor(int userInput)
{
    int i=0;
    int buffer=-1;
    int x=0,y=1;
    System.out.println("Input: " + userInput);
    while(i<1000000){
        if(x==userInput){
            System.out.println("Belongs to sequence: Yes "");
            break;
        }
        else{
            if(userInput>buffer&&userInput<x){
                System.out.println("Belongs to sequence: No ");
                System.out.println("Nearest Elements: " + buffer+","+x);
                break;
            }
        }

        buffer=x;
        int temp=y;
        y=x+y;
        x=temp;
        i++;
    }


}   

}
```