# Get a a position in Array to insert a new element sorted using binary search

Tags: java

I could use your help on this. I am trying to create a method that would do a binary search for a position where a new element would be inserted, use a natural order compare method in the process, the code that I have written is wrong obviously, I'm new to writing algorithims and just not sure how to implement this. so for example

```
int[] list = {10,15,20,25,30};
```

and I want to insert 17, I have another method that would add it but I need the position it would go in by doing a binary search and compare method assuming natural order. Thanks in advance for all your help. This is what I have so far but when I try and insert 53 it gives position 4 instead of 5. Any suggestions?

```
public int getIndex(E element) {
    E e = (E)element;
    int low = 0;
    int high = this.size;
    int mid = 0;

    if(size == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (low <= high) {
           mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (list[mid]== null) {
            return mid;
        }

            if (compare(e, list[mid]) < 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else if (compare(e, list[mid]) > 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                return (int) list[mid];
            } 


    }
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.binary_search` will return a negative index you can use to determine the insert location. However, this assumes your input is sorted, which does not hold for your example. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-

Comment: I cannot use Java binary_search and the list is assumed sorted prior to the element being added

Comment: Have you already seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245166/find-the-nearest-closest-value-in-a-sorted-list>?

Comment: *"I'm new to writing algorithims and just not sure how to implement this. "* - Advice: you won't learn how to do this by copy other people's code.  And I presume that you are doing this exercise because you *want* to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't posted any code, here's a hint:

1. Start from the middle index of the array.  In your case, this will be index 2, holding 20.
2. We can see that 20 is larger than the number you wish to insert (17), so we navigate to the middle index of the lower half of the array (`{10, 15}` - in this case, index 1).
3. Because there are only 2 elements, we check the value of the higher element first (15).
4. 17 is greater than 15, so we would want to navigate to the next, higher sub-array, but it's empty!
5. This means that you're ready to insert your value (17) at the index right after 15 (in this case, 17 would be placed at index 2).

Keep in mind that, for a binary search to work, the array needs to be sorted.  It isn't in your example.

Comment: I see and I apologize, I corrected the array above. So would I have the comparison in a While loop that check both elements?

Comment: You could.  Recursion could work as well for something like this.