# Find second nearest value always return last nearest value

Tags: java, android, if-statement, coordinates, closest

I want to find nearest value from my data set. The first value is returning right data, but second value is returning last nearest data. For example if i have `7, 11, 12, 15, 17, 20` and i have parameter values is 10 it should return first nearst value = 11 and second nearest value = 12. But when i try, the second value is not 12 but 20. First value will give right return but the second nearest value will always show the last nearest value, not second nearest.

Here's my code:

```
String closestPosition = null;

            ArrayList<Router> wifis = db.getFriendlyWifis(building);

            double min_distance = positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(0), wifis);
            closestPosition = positionsData.get(0).getName();
            String res = "";
            res += closestPosition + "\n" + min_distance;
            res += "\n" + positionsData.get(0).toString();
            int j=0;
            for (int i = 1; i < positionsData.size(); i++) {
                double distance = positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(i), wifis);
                res += "\n" + positionsData.get(i).getName() + "\n" + distance;
                res += "\n" + positionsData.get(i).toString();
                if (distance < min_distance) {
                    min_distance = distance;
                    closestPosition = positionsData.get(i).getName();
                    j=i;
                }

            }
            if (min_distance == PositionData.MAX_DISTANCE){
                closestPosition="OUT OF RANGE";
                Toast.makeText(this,"You are out of range of the selected building",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            result.setText("Nearest point :  "+ closestPosition);
            res += "\nCurrent:\n" + positionData.toString();
            Log.v("Result",res);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////

            min_distance = positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(0), wifis);
            String closestPosition2 = null;

            closestPosition2 = positionsData.get(0).getName();
            res = "";
            res += closestPosition2 + "\n" + min_distance;
            res += "\n" + positionsData.get(0).toString();
            for (int i = 1; i < positionsData.size(); i=i+2) { if(j!=i){
                    double distance = positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(i), wifis);
                    res += "\n" + positionsData.get(i).getName() + "\n" + distance;
                    res += "\n" + positionsData.get(i).toString();
                    closestPosition2 = positionsData.get(i).getName();//////////////////////////
                    if(closestPosition2.equals(closestPosition))
                        continue;
                    if (distance < min_distance) {
                        min_distance = distance;
                        closestPosition2 = positionsData.get(i).getName();

                    }
                }
            }

            if (min_distance == PositionData.MAX_DISTANCE){
                closestPosition2="OUT OF RANGE";
                Toast.makeText(this,"You are out of range of the selected building",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            result2.setText("Nearest point :  "+ closestPosition2);
```

Here's the output:

```
V/closest1:: f
V/closest2:: e
```

here's the log:

```
 d
    36.0
    d(4.0,4.0)
    UGM-Secure : -63.0
    eduroam : -63.0
    UGM-Hotspot : -42.0

    a
    64.0
    a(1.0,1.0)
    UGM-Hotspot : -40.0

    f
    17.0
    f(6.0,6.0)
    UGM-Secure : -65.0
    eduroam : -66.0
    UGM-Hotspot : -46.0

    b
    25.0
    b(2.0,2.0)
    UGM-Secure : -60.0
    eduroam : -59.0
    UGM-Hotspot : -48.0

    c
    89.0
    c(3.0,3.0)
    UGM-Secure : -60.0
    eduroam : -59.0
    UGM-Hotspot : -40.0

    e
    94.0
    e(5.0,5.0)
    UGM-Secure : -65.0
    eduroam : -66.0
    UGM-Hotspot : -39.0
```

If the first nearest value is f with value 17, the second nearest value is whether b or d right? but why it return e that have farthest value? I'm also looking for 3rd nearest value actually, if there's also way to find 3rd nearest value it will be great.

Edit : Here's my PositionData class

```
public class PositionData implements Serializable {
    public static final int MAX_DISTANCE=99999999;
    private String name;
    double x;
    double y;
    public static final int MINIMUM_COMMON_ROUTERS=1;
    public HashMap<String, Double> values;
    public HashMap<String,String> routers;



    public PositionData(String name, double x, double y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name=name;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        values = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        routers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    }



    public void addValue(Router router, double strength){

        values.put(router.getBSSID(), strength);
        routers.put(router.getBSSID(),router.getSSID());

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public Double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result="";
        result+=name+"("+x+","+y+")"+"\n";
        for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e: this.values.entrySet())
            result+=routers.get(e.getKey())+" : "+e.getValue().toString()+"\n";

        return result;

    }
    public HashMap<String, Double> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    public double uDistance(PositionData arg,ArrayList<Router> friendlyWifis){
        double sum=0;
        double count=0;
        for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e: this.values.entrySet()){
            Double v;
            //Log.v("Key : ",arg.values.get(e.getKey()).toString());
            if(isFriendlyWifi(friendlyWifis,e.getKey()) && arg.values.containsKey(e.getKey()))
            {
                v=arg.values.get(e.getKey());
                sum+=Math.pow((v-e.getValue()),2);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count<MINIMUM_COMMON_ROUTERS){
            sum=MAX_DISTANCE;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private boolean isFriendlyWifi(ArrayList<Router> wifis, String bssid){
        for(int i=0;i<wifis.size();i++){
            if(wifis.get(i).getBSSID().equals(bssid))
                return true;

        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
    private final static int POSITIONS_ARRAY_SIZE = 3; //Global constant in the Activity.


    String closestPosition = null;
    String closestPosition2 = null;
    String closestPosition3 = null;
    ArrayList<Router> wifis = db.getFriendlyWifis(building);
    boolean flagPositionInserted;

    ArrayList<Integer> min_distance_positions = new ArrayList<>();
    //Get the first value (position = 0).
    double min_distance = positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(0), wifis);
    min_distance_positions.add(0);
    String res = "";
    res += closestPosition + "\n" + min_distance;
    res += "\n" + positionsData.get(0).toString();

    //Iterate through the datalist (positionsData).
    for (int i = 1; i < positionsData.size(); i++) {
        double distance = positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(i), wifis);
        res += "\n" + positionsData.get(i).getName() + "\n" + distance;
        res += "\n" + positionsData.get(i).toString();

        flagPositionInserted = false;
        //Iterate through the sorted list (min_distance_positions).
        for (int j = 0; j < min_distance_positions.size(); j++){
            if (distance < positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(j)), wifis)) {
                min_distance_positions.add(j, i);
                flagPositionInserted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!flagPositionInserted) {
            if (min_distance_positions.size() < POSITIONS_ARRAY_SIZE) {
                min_distance_positions.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    //min_distance_positions.size() should be less or equal to 3(POSITIONS_ARRAY_SIZE).
    //min_distance_positions.get(0) is the closestPosition.
    //min_distance_positions.get(1) is the 2nd closestPosition.
    //min_distance_positions.get(2) is the 3rd closestPosition.
    String msg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < min_distance_positions.size(); i++){
        msg += min_distance_positions.get(i) + ", ";
    }
    Log.v("Result", "Position ArrayList Content: " + msg);

    closestPosition = positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(0)).getName();
    if (positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(0)), wifis) >= PositionData.MAX_DISTANCE){
        closestPosition="OUT OF RANGE";
        Toast.makeText(this,"You are out of range of the selected building",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    result.setText("Nearest point :  "+ closestPosition);
    res += "\nCurrent:\n" + positionData.toString();
    Log.v("Result", res);

    closestPosition2 = positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(1)).getName();
    if (positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(1)), wifis) >= PositionData.MAX_DISTANCE){
        closestPosition2="OUT OF RANGE";
        Toast.makeText(this,"You are out of range of the selected building",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    result2.setText("Nearest point :  "+ closestPosition2);
    closestPosition3 = positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(2)).getName();
    if (positionData.uDistance(positionsData.get(min_distance_positions.get(2)), wifis) >= PositionData.MAX_DISTANCE){
        closestPosition3="OUT OF RANGE";
        Toast.makeText(this,"You are out of range of the selected building",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    result3.setText("Nearest point :  "+ closestPosition3);
```

The code is to use **INSERTION SORT** to sort your points according to their distance and store the point position in another ArrayList (min_distance_positions). From your sample data, original order is: d(position 0), a(position 1), f(position 2), b(position 3), c(position 4), e(position 5). The sorted order is : 2(f), 3(b), 0(d), 1(a), 4(c), 5(e). `if (min_distance_positions.size() < POSITIONS_ARRAY_SIZE)` is to control the output ArrayList (min_distance_positions) size, so now the msg is only: 2, 3, 0,. If this code is omitted, then the msg is: 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 5,

Hope that helps!

Comment: i get this mesage in run ```SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database  was leaked! Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.```

Comment: so we remove first nearest value with ```min_distance_positions.remove(POSITIONS_ARRAY_SIZE)``` and then we can look  for second nearest value?  or that code is for 3 nearest value?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not to understand, should i write code for ```//min_distance_positions.size() should be less or equal to 3(POSITIONS_ARRAY_SIZE).
    //min_distance_positions.get(0) is the 1st closestPosition.
    //min_distance_positions.get(1) is the 2nd closestPosition.
    //min_distance_positions.size2) is the 3rd closestPosition.``` ?

Comment: So i need to rewrite it, and  change j with 1 and 2 to get second, and third nearest point? and why to get 3rd closestPosition using ```//min_distance_positions.size(2)``` while 1st and 2nd is using ```//min_distance_positions.get(1/2)```

Comment: Updated the code to show how to display result2 and result3, and added more comments :-)

Comment: it can't ```positionData.uDistance(closestPosition, wifis)``` because closestPosition is String while positionData.uDistance is for double, closest position should be positionsData, it's value in database.

Comment: Also i need another field from database, not only name.

Comment: Woah, thank's, that's what i was looking for. Now i can also get another field from the database. I've trying using HashMap and sort it, then get 3 first index but i can't get another field like X from that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the nearest value

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
numbers[0] = 100;
numbers[1] = -34200;
numbers[2] = 3040;
numbers[3] = 400433;
numbers[4] = 500;
numbers[5] = -100;
numbers[6] = -200;
numbers[7] = 532;
numbers[8] = 6584;
numbers[9] = -945;

int myNumber = 50;
int distance = Math.abs(numbers[0] - myNumber);
int idx = 0;
for(int c = 1; c < numbers.length; c++){
    int cdistance = Math.abs(numbers[c] - myNumber);
    if(cdistance < distance){
        idx = c;
        distance = cdistance;
    }
}
int nearestNumber = numbers[idx];
```

Comment: I already get nearest value. my question is about second nearest value and third nearest value.

Comment: This link might help [Nearest value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-closest-elements-given-value/) and [closest value in a sorted List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245166/find-the-nearest-closest-value-in-a-sorted-list) Please check

Comment: It's not sorted. The value for parameter is under point name in output

Answer (score 0):

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            int[] numbers = new int[10];
            numbers[0] = 100;
            numbers[1] = -34200;
            numbers[2] = 3040;
            numbers[3] = 400433;
            numbers[4] = 500;
            numbers[5] = -100;
            numbers[6] = -100;
            numbers[7] = 532;
            numbers[8] = 6584;
            numbers[9] = -945;
            // my number 
            int myNumber = 150;
            Arrays.sort(numbers);

// for first nearest value
            int num = valnearest(numbers, myNumber);
            int firstnearestNumber = numbers[num];
            System.out.println("firstnearestNumber--->" + firstnearestNumber);

 // for Second nearest value
            numbers = removeTheElement(numbers, num);

            int newnum = valnearest(numbers, myNumber);
            int secondnearestNumber = numbers[newnum];
            System.out.println("secondnearestNumber--->" + secondnearestNumber);

        }

        public static int valnearest(int[] numbers, int myNumber) {
            int idx = 0;
            int lastdistance = -1;
            for (int c = 0; c < numbers.length; c++) {
                int distance = Math.abs(numbers[c] - myNumber);

                if (lastdistance != -1) {
                    if (distance < lastdistance) {
                        idx = c;
                    }
                }
                lastdistance = distance;

            }

            return idx;
        }

        public static int[] removeTheElement(int[] arr,
                                             int index) {

            // If the array is empty 
            // or the index is not in array range 
            // return the original array 
            if (arr == null
                    || index < 0
                    || index >= arr.length) {

                return arr;
            }

            // Create another array of size one less 
            int[] anotherArray = new int[arr.length - 1];

            // Copy the elements except the index 
            // from original array to the other array 
            for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                // if the index is 
                // the removal element index 
                if (i == index) {
                    continue;
                }

                // if the index is not 
                // the removal element index 
                anotherArray[k++] = arr[i];
            }

            // return the resultant array 
            return anotherArray;
        }
    }
```